# ORA-01438 Error

Tags: oracle, plsql, ora-06512, ora-01438

Can anyone help me with this exception?

> ORA-01438: value larger than specified precision allowed for this column
>
> ORA-06512: at "DM001.DFEE_AFT_IUD_JOURNAL", line 58
>
> ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'DM001.DFEE_AFT_IUD_JOURNAL' ORA-06512: at line 4

Comment: Edit your question to show your code and your table DDL.

Comment: http://ora-01438.ora-code.com/

Comment: What happened was the Primary Key was set up as a NUMBER(3) and when the value got to 999 the sequence started throwing this error.  That is why it seemed to come out of no where when nothing had changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to insert a value in any column that has a "precision" larger than the defined.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to store a value into the field of a record that is longer than the column definition of the table allows.

Your column might be defined as NUMBER(3), but you're trying to store a longer number like 1250 into it.

Answer (score 1):

You've probably tried to enter a value greater than de defined when you created the table (i.e. varchar2(4) -> value tried 10000)